# typescript method inside method returns is not a function

Tags: typescript

I'm facing a strange error in typescript ( strange in my prespective of course, it might be totally natural for other people ).

So, if I have a class:

```
class SuperClass{

   func_1 = (): void =>{
       console.log('func 1');
   }
   func_2 = (): void =>{
       console.log('func 2');
   }

   func_3 = (): void =>{
       this.func_1();
   }
}
```

And I have this method that invokes other method I find myself having the following error: TypeError: this.func_1 is not a function .

How can I invoke a method inside a method in typescript?

Comment: Entering your exact code in the TypeScript playground (http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground) seems to compile just fine. Perhaps your version of TypeScript is out of date?

Answer (score 0):

I just found that I needed to add an underscore to the called method.

```
func_3 = (): void =>{
       **_**this.func_1();
}
```

Probably my typescript is old or something.

Thanks for the reply